# How to map html table header cell to a row cell via css or xpath selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, css-selectors

So I have data structured like that in page:

```
<!-- some html-->
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th><th>Type</th><th>Value</th> <!-- Header I need -->
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
<!-- some html-->
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="insertGuidHere">
            <td>eventDate</td><td>eventType</td><td>eventData</td> <!-- Values I need to map -->
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a header row and somewhere down the line in a different table on a different level I have the data row (an overly complex kendo-grid). I can't go from one to another via a reasonable xpath, but I know that indices match correctly.

What I want is a way to map header index to data. Something like reverse `nth-child()` - I find the element by text and return its index

```
var x = $x("//th[contains(text(),'Value')]")[0].findIndexAmongSiblings(); // returns 3, because it's 3rd header cell
$("tr#insertGuidHere > td:nth-child(" + x + ")"); // returns eventData cell
```

I know there is an `.index()` function in jQuery, but I couldn't get it to run properly, that is to return a numeric.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML table DOM a cell has a property `cellIndex` (starts with 0) so you can find the index for XPath with e.g. `x.cellIndex + 1`. Then you can use `"id('insertGuidHere')/td[" + (x.cellIndex + 1) + "]"` in XPath to select the third cell. That will of course also work with e.g. `//tbody/tr/td[3]` to select all third cells of all rows.